# sudo apt update sudo apt upgrade updated all but firefox

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade, firefox

Looking at "similar questions", I did not find my issue. When running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, it updated all BUT Firefox. Any suggestions/corrections?

I originally installed Firefox via `snap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications installed using `snap` are not updated via the system package manager.

You can use `sudo snap refresh` to update all your snap packages manually, or run `sudo snap refresh [packageName]` to update a specific package. Based on the comments it appears you have installed firefox using snap.

However, according to the snap documentation, all snaps are automatically updated daily. You may not need to manually update, but better safe than sorry. Please see https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started for more information on updating snap packages.

Comment: OK thanks. One thing I forgot (that may or may not be of any issue) is the "About" menu for Firefox say the admin has disabled updates. I will do as you have advised. Again, thanks.